# MVC модель, Url без контроллера

Tags: mvc

Подскажите пожалуйста, каким образом получают подобный путь : `https://www.somesite.ua/elektronika/noutbuki-i-aksesuary/noutbuki/`? Если `elektronika` контроллер, тогда это создает проблему добавления новой категории и дальше по цепочке тоже. По сути весь этот URL должен быть `slug`, а где же контроллер и `action` метод, его прячут при помощи `.htaccsess`? Дайте пожалуйста пищи для размышления.

Answer (score 0):

там вроде присутствует параметер id или могут быть вложеные маршруты

[Определение маршрутов](https://metanit.com/sharp/mvc5/6.1.php)

[Маршрутизация и вложенные ресурсы](https://metanit.com/sharp/mvc5/6.8.php)